# Grails: How do get the model passed via <g:include inside the action before it gets to the view?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

One way of passing data to the view from `<g:include` is my passing data via the `model` attribute. How do I get that data from the controller action passed in to `<g:include`?

For example I did. `<g:include controller="Book" action="list" model="${name: 'xyz'}" />`

I could't access the value stored in the `model` attribute from inside the `list` action. But variable `name` with value `xyz` was available in `list.gsp`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain it more.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Updated. Clear now?

Comment: Nope, still not :-) Based on my understanding, you are in any action (other than `list`) and you want to include the response of `list` action of `Book` controller and you want to pass a parameter `name` with value `xyz` to the `list` action of `Book` controller?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal yes but not via `params` but `model` attribute of the taglib.

Answer (score 0):

You access these parameters the same way you usually access parameters in Grails - by using the params object. The 'model' passed in is just a map which grails binds to the params object.

For example, let's say you have the following line in a GSP.

```
<%-- Just an example, you probably shouldn't set a map this way. --%>
${someModel = [someParam: 'SomeValue'] }
<g:include model="${someModel}" controller="someController" action="someAction" />
```

Then inside your someController/someAction you could access this model by doing:

```
if (params.someParam) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: I tried this. I didn't work. I, however found the map valued on the view rendered by the controller.